# I need to render as UTF-8 encoding but getting encoding issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, utf-8, httpcontext

Sorry this might have been answered a million different ways but I figured my issue might have a different problem.

So I have this value I want to show on the page. The value is saved in UTF-8 format and I have a page being rendered in UTF-8(sounds good so far);

My setback, is that the way the value is being store it's not showing it utf format, but rather in this : **ãƒãƒ£ãƒ¼ãƒˆè¨­å®š**

So my question is how do I find out the encoding type of the garbled text and get it so that its correctly in UTF-8?

The correct version should look like this **チャート設定**

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "not showing in utf format", what are you using to display it? Is this the way it's coming up on the page? Also when you say "page rendered in UTF-8" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I have my Response charset set to UTF-8, so I'm trying to figure out how I can take ( ãƒãƒ£ãƒ¼ãƒˆè¨­å®š) and convert it to UTF-8 and have it render correctly on the page

Comment: You should do something before you get this `garbled text` otherwise your text is `garbled` and you can not convert it correctly to UTF-8.

Comment: I'm getting the text from a stored procedure, do you think I should address it at the data level?

Comment: I think so, since your `garbled` string is already converted using some encoding which seems to be wrong. this conversion may have lost some chars/bytes which can make it impossible to convert to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

So this question seems to vague and probably will be addressed differently. I've found a way to parse the data correctly, I'm going to work more with the data values to fix this problem.
Thanks to @L.B and @Mark Ransom for feedback!